# How to add an extra row of 1's at top of a NumPy array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

An array is present as:

```
a[[12,31,5], [5,32,1]]
```

I wish to add a row of 1's such that it becomes:

```
a[[1,1,1], [12,31,5], [5,32,1]]
```

How to do it?

Comment: Look into [numpy.concatenate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html#numpy.concatenate).

Answer (score 0):

All you need is [np.vstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html):

```
a= np.array([[12,31,5], [5,32,1]])
np.vstack([np.ones(a.shape[1]),a])

array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [12., 31.,  5.],
       [ 5., 32.,  1.]])
```

A slightly more involved is [np.r_](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html):

```
np.r_[np.ones(a.shape[1]).reshape((1,-1)),a]
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [12., 31.,  5.],
       [ 5., 32.,  1.]])
```